# How to add a new member using values from existing members?

Tags: powershell, parsing

In PowerShell, I get the following output from `Get-DHCPServerv4-Lease`:

```
    IPAddress       ScopeId         ClientId             HostName             AddressState         LeaseExpiryTime
    ---------       -------         --------             --------             ------------         ---------------
    192.0.2.0.17    192.0.2.0       ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff    hostname.domain      Active               6/12/2020 11:38:31 AM
    192.0.2.0.18    192.0.2.0       ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-fe    hostname.domain      Active               7/12/2020 11:38:31 AM
```

which is stored in an object `$o`.

What I need is a new member *Host* of the object that holds only the hostname, not the FQDN.
The data is then stored in a csv file. Unfortunately I cannot parse the original "HostName"-member later on.

I need something like this:

```
$o | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Host -Value ($_.HostName.split(".")[0])
```

But it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your variable only has the one value changing your line to something like this should do the trick (basically replacing `_` with `o`).

```
$o | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Host -Value ($o.HostName.split(".")[0])
```

Comment: that is in fact true, but unfortunately my output Object `$o` can have more than one member. I updated the question